# Wildcard subdomain in Ngnix

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I want to configure Nginx as a reverse proxy. But i want to configure it only for a part of subdomain, which is dyanamic. I tried with `*` and it didnt work. Can anyone help me here.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  (dynamic_part)-clientapp.mydomain.com;

    location / {
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To quote [the manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#wildcard_names): "A wildcard name may contain an asterisk only on the name’s start or end, and only on a dot border". You could use a regular expression `server_name` instead.

Answer (score 1):

the reason the * is not working:

> A wildcard name may contain an asterisk only on the name’s start or end, and only on a dot border. The names “www.*.example.org” and “w*.example.org” are invalid. However, these names can be specified using regular expressions, for example, “~^www..+.example.org$” and “~^w.*.example.org$”. An asterisk can match several name parts. The name “*.example.org” matches not only www.example.org but www.sub.example.org as well.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Did you try it with a regex, like as example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  ~(.*)-clientapp\.mydomain\.com;


    location / {
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work. It works for both ```abc-clientapp.mydomain.com``` and ```abc.mydomain.com```.